# CSS flex property is not allowing links to be hidden and stack. Is this also not allowing my hamburger menu to function properly?

Tags: html, css

Inside my navbar, are my links. I am trying to set a media query where the links stack and center after clicking my hamburger menu with primely CSS flex-box. What do I need to change to my code to achieve this?

I was using float, absolute and relative positioning first. At this time my navbar was working almost perfectly. However, I had to place my link with its href="home," outside of the div with class "options," so that it would remain visible after my screen size approached my media query. The positioning of my links became awkward after this so I turned to CSS flex-box.

```
   <html>
<div>
<nav class="navbar">
    <label class="menu" for="toggle">&#9776</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
    <div class="main"><li class="home"><a href="home">TechReality</a></li></div>
    <div class="options">
       <li class="news"><a href="news"></a></li>
        <li class="products"><a href="productstats">Categories</a></li>
        <li class="trends"><a href="trending">Trending</a></li>
        <li class="forum"><a href="reading">Customer Forum</a></li>
        <li class="about"><a href="aboutus"></a>About Us</li>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1135px) {
.navbar .options .home{
    visibility: visible;
}

.menu {
    display: block; 
    cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar.options{
    text-align: center;
    visibility: hidden;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.news, .products, .trends, .forum, .about {
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3); 
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
    margin: 0;
}

ul:last-of-type a {
    border-bottom: none;
  }

#toggle:checked + .options {
    visibility: visible;
}
}
```

My full code can be seen in this codepen snippet https://codepen.io/ashu121805/full/XvgRqP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot to discuss here, but I want to point out three major problems that will get you 90% of the way there, then you can tweak the styling as you see fit afterwards.

## 1. Fixing invalid HTML

You have an extraneous closing `div` tag inside of `<nav class="navbar">` that should be deleted. You also have `li` tags inside of `div`, which is incorrect; an `li` should always be the child of either an `ol` or a `ul`. Fixing those, and deleting the extra `html` opening tag from the start of your snippet above, we get this:

```
<div>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <label class="menu" for="toggle">&#9776</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
    <ul class="main">
      <li class="home"><a href="home">TechReality</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="options">
      <li class="news"><a href="news"></a></li>
      <li class="products"><a href="productstats">Categories</a></li>
      <li class="trends"><a href="trending">Trending</a></li>
      <li class="forum"><a href="reading">Customer Forum</a></li>
      <li class="about"><a href="aboutus"></a>About Us</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

(Also, just a note: In CodePen, you don't need to include the `html` or `body` tags, nor the `head` section. You can also delete the `script` tag you have and just use the JS panel in the editor view.)

## 2. Making the hamburger menu work

This one is very easy to fix. Right now you are toggling your menu's visibility with this rule:

```
#toggle:checked + .options {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Problem is, the `+` selector only selects the *immediately next* sibling of an element. Since `.options` isn't right after `#toggle`, the selector doesn't work.

Instead, you can use the `~` selector, which will select *all* siblings after an element that match the selector:

```
#toggle:checked ~ .options {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

## 3. Basic CSS cleanup

Once you get this far, you'll have a menu that toggles when you click the hamburger, but it'll look wonky. There's a few main things we need to do:

1. Make our lists (`ul`) not actually look like lists.
2. Make the links stack on top of each other vertically.
3. Position the links in a logical place, like right below the nav bar on the left side of the screen.

#1 can be accomplished simply:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

#2 can be accomplished by adding these additional styles:

```
.navbar .options {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.news, .products, .trends, .forum, .about {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Also note that you currently have a typo in your media query styles – there should be a space in `.navbar .options` where you currently have none.

#3 is a little more involved, but a good start would be to add these styles inside your media query:

```
/* force .options to wrap below since it has flex-basis: 100% */
.navbar {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
/* remove the default margin-bottom on lists – or you could do this in your main styles above your media query */
.navbar .options,
.main {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

From there you can adjust things as you like.